# SQL: flag if value exists in the past

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2012, with columns like:

```
Client_ID, Sale_Date
```

I need 2 additional flag columns:

```
FirstPurchase, ActiveWithin90Days
```

"FirstPurchase" shoud take one of these 2 values: **new**, or **old**.
**New** means the Client_ID value is identified for the first time given the existing time frame.
**Old** means the value has already been identified for the first time in the past.

"ActiveWithin90Days" should take one of these 2 values: **1** or **0**.
Value **1** means Client_ID value exists in the previous 90 days. Value **0** means it does NOT exist in the past 90 days.

The desired output looks like this:

```
Client_ID    Sale_Date    FirstPurchase    ActiveWithin90Days
1           2013-03-01       new              1
2           2013-04-01       new              1
1           2013-05-01       old              1
1           2013-09-01       old              0
3           2013-10-01       new              1
```

Comment: Can you post the query that you tried? Also, I'm not quite sure what your question is.

Comment: I would not name your columns Flag1 and Flag2. Give them a reasonable name like FirstPurchase and ActiveWithin90Days.

Comment: You shouldn't persist a field that depends on other data in the table - if you change or delete data all of the affected records will need to be updated as well.  Better to do that in a view or sproc.

Comment: You should be able to accomplish this using computed columns.  Basically, let SQL server do the hard part.

Comment: New client considered active within 90 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a sub query that finds the first sale date.  Something like:

```
        select s.ClientID,
        s.Sale_Date,
        case when s.Sale_Date = m.MinSales_Date then 1 else 0 end AS IsFirstSale,
        case when dateadd(day, -90, getdate()) < m.MinSale_Date then 1 else 0 end 
              AS IsNewAccount
        from Sales s
        inner join (select m.ClientId,
                    MIN(m.Sale_Date) MinSale_Date
                    from Sales m
                    group by m.ClientId) m
        on s.ClientID = m.ClientId
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ClientID ORDER BY Sale_Date)
  FROM YourTable
)
SELECT A.ClientID,
       A.Sale_Date,
       CASE WHEN RN = 1 THEN 'new' ELSE 'old' END Flag1,
       CASE WHEN B.ClientID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Flag2
FROM CTE A
OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
             FROM YourTable
             WHERE ClientID = A.ClientID
             AND Sale_Date <= DATEADD(DAY,-90,A.Sale_Date)) B
```

[**Here is**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/35809/7) an sqlfiddle with a demo.

And the results are:

```
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════╦═══════╗
║ ClientID ║ Sale_Date  ║ Flag1 ║ Flag2 ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═══════╬═══════╣
║        1 ║ 2013-03-01 ║ new   ║     1 ║
║        1 ║ 2013-05-01 ║ old   ║     1 ║
║        1 ║ 2013-09-01 ║ old   ║     0 ║
║        2 ║ 2013-04-01 ║ new   ║     1 ║
║        3 ║ 2013-10-01 ║ new   ║     1 ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve `Sale_Date` of the first purchase with `MIN(Sale_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID)` and compare it to the current row's `Sale_Date` to determine if this row *is* the first purchase.

Use `LAG(Sale_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY Sale_Date)` to retrieve the date of the previous purchase to see if it is more than 90 days earlier than the current purchase's date. Naturally, a first purchase would not have a corresponding previous one and so marking it as active or inactive within 90 days would make little sense. Nevertheless, it is possible to default the flag to either value depending on how you compare the dates.

[Here is an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/f9038/1) of a single query using both functions mentioned:

```
SELECT
  Client_ID,
  Sale_Date,
  FirstPurchase       = CASE Sale_Date
                          WHEN MIN(Sale_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID)
                          THEN 'new'
                          ELSE 'old'
                        END,
  ActiveWithin90Days  = CASE
                          WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY,
                            LAG(Sale_Date) OVER (PARTITION BY Client_ID ORDER BY Sale_Date),
                            Sale_Date
                          ) > 90
                          THEN 0
                          ELSE 1
                        END
FROM
  dbo.atable
;
```

More information:

- [OVER Clause (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)
- [Analytic Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213234.aspx)

  - [LAG (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx)